# How do I diff a Helm template against an existing deployment/release?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

It looks like Helm 3 is making this more difficult: https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff/issues/176

But I'm finding that using the helm-diff plugin OR just doing this: `helm template releaseName chart | kubectl diff -f - | bat -l diff -` I'm seeing ALL resources as new with "+" next to them. Why is this?

I'm running these commands:

```
# upgrade
helm upgrade --install --create-namespace \
    --namespace derps -f helm/deploy-values.yaml \
    --set 'parentChart.param1=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param2=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param3=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param4=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param5=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    myapp helm/mychart

# make no changes and try to diff
helm template \
    --namespace derps -f helm/deploy-values.yaml \
    --set 'parentChart.param1=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param2=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param3=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param4=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param5=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    myapp helm/mychart | kubectl diff -f - | bat -l diff -
```

I get output that shows the ENTIRE manifest is new- why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need `-n derps` on the diff too. If memory serves me, `helm template --namespace` doesn't actually inject the value.

Comment: Yup I wasn't thinking, I needed the namespace set on kubectl. One thing I see now though is it seems all my `helm.sh/hook: test` are "new" each time- is that expected?

Comment: Yes, those are "magic" values, normally Helm doesn't actually run those like normal.

Comment: its storing them in the release object though, would be nice to diff my "test" manifests too. If I can't do that is there at least an easy way to filter them out entirely?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3):

did you try:

```sh
helm template \
    --namespace derps --no-hooks --skip-tests \
    -f helm/deploy-values.yaml \
    --set 'parentChart.param1=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param2=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param3=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param4=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    --set 'parentChart.param5=sdfsdfsdfdsf' \
    myapp helm/mychart | kubectl diff --namespace derps -f - | bat -l diff -
```